# How to extract part of a string value in json object using jq parser

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I have a json file which contains an array of objects. I need to extract them into a comma separated file. However, there is one of the values (cipher) that has multiple values separated by spaces. I need to extract (parse) them into two formats: 
1) Each value separated by comma.

2) Only the first value before the first space.

My json file contains:

```
[{ "host": "xys.com", "ip": "0.20.0.4", "port": 222, "cipher": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD"}]
```

I use this jq command:

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | "\(.host),\(.ip),\(.cipher)"' > test_parsing.txt
```

Which gives me:

```
xys.com,0.20.0.4,TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

What I want is two formts:

1) Separate the cipher values by commas and if there is an `=` sign, take what comes after it:

```
xys.com,0.20.0.4,TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,TLSv1.2,ECDH,RSA,AESGCM(128),AEAD
```

2) Extract just the first part of the `cipher` value which is:

```
xys.com,0.20.0.4,TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

How can I extract the two formats from mu `json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight mismatch between the given JSON input, the stated requirements, and the expected output, so I will focus on the requirements and the given input.

### (1)

```
.[]
| .cipher |= gsub(" *(?<x>[A-Za-z]+)=(?<y>[^ ]+)"; "," + .y)
| .cipher |= (split(" |,") | join(","))
| "\(.host),\(.ip),\(.cipher)"
```

produces

```
xys.com,0.20.0.4,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2,ECDH,RSA,AESGCM(128),AEAD
```

### (2)

```
.[]
| .cipher |= (split(" ")[0])
| "\(.host),\(.ip),\(.cipher)"
```

produces

```
xys.com,0.20.0.4,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```